# How IIS Schedule process request

Tags: concurrency, iis-7.5, httprequest, iis-express

I need your help regarding IIS request handling.

1. Does IIS process request per web page or operation inside the page ?
2. How  IIS assign work order for different web page having multiple operation inside ? Does it will complete one page request before handling the other ? or it will process simultaneously ?

Answer (score 0):

IIS architecture is documented in details here,

http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/introduction-to-iis/introduction-to-iis-architecture

while the ASP.NET lifecycle is here,

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb470252.aspx

Combining the two you can see that IIS does not care whether the request is to a page or inside the page. It simply passes the request to ASP.NET modules/handlers.

In the same sense, IIS does not assign work order either. First come first serve.